# How do I give async queue.push a callback?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) modules [push](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) Control Flow and wondering how I can give the function/method I `q.push()` the callback that is given at `async.queue`?

```
var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
    task();
    callback();
}, 1);

q.push((function(userService){
    // stuff to be done
})(user.Services[i]));
```

I guess it's something like `task(callback);` but how is that received whith the other arguments like *userService*?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example on how to do that:

```
var q = async.queue(function (userService, callback) {
  console.log('Here you do your stuff with the userService object');
  console.log('Calling the callback function');
  callback(null, userService);
}, 1);

q.push(userService, function (err, userService) {
  console.log('finished processing ' + userService.name);
});
```

As you can see the push function takes 2 params, an object and a callback function (that can have as many arguments as you like).
Then in the queue function, you process your "job" (you'll use the first param - object) and after you considered the "job" finished you call the callback function (which is defined as the 2nd param on the push function).

I haven't tried this myself but I've read the documentation here: https://github.com/caolan/async#queue

Answer (score 3):

What you are pushing is the 'return' value of the self invoking function. So in the queue task is the return value. In this this case, task would be a function accepting another function as callback. Arguments for the call back would be the same arguments that it is called with the task function.

```
var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
    task("I'm a service!",callback);
}, 1);

q.push(function(userService,callback){
    doSomeStuff(userService);
    callback(userService);//stuff finished, call the callback given...
}); // we are passing a function here(not a self invoking function that returns value)

q.drain = function(userService){ // this will be invoked after finishing the queue
   stuff(userService);
}
```

In this example we push a function to the queue, that accepts two arguments, userService and callback. In the queue function will be called with "I'm a service!" as userService, and the callback from the queue function arguements. After finishing the function pushed the callback will be fired with the userService passed which was userService, and that tells async module that this function has finished work, do the next.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used async.queue as mutex, concurrency=1, to enforce execution of a single async task (with external callback) per queue type:

```
    function processMyAsyncTaskOnebyOne(params, extCallback){
     let queue = this.queues[params.QKey];
     if (!queue) {
         queue = async.queue(function (task, qTaskCallback) {
                 task(qTaskCallback);
         }, 1);
         queue.saturated = function () {
             console.log('queue is saturated ' + params.QKey);
         };
         this.queues[params.QKey] = queue;
     }
     var that = this;
     return queue.push(function (qTaskCallback) {
            console.log('start new queue task ' + params.QKey);
            that.myAsyncTask(params, qTaskCallback);
     }, function (err, result) {
       // wrap callback
       console.log('finished queue task ' + params.QKey);
       if (extCallback) extCallback(err, result);
     });

    }
```